# Does "bull" utilize multicore as node.js runs single-threaded

Tags: node.js, multithreading

according to this package https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull#documentation

> The process function can also be run in a separate process. This has several advantages:
>
> - The process is sandboxed so if it crashes it does not affect the
>     worker.
> - You can run blocking code without affecting the queue (jobs will not
>     stall).
> - Much better utilization of multi-core CPUs.
> - Less connections to redis.
>
> In order to use this feature just create a separate file with the processor.
>   (..) This is a perfect way to run blocking code.

My Question is:

does Bull utilize automatically multi-Core CPU as node.js runs on Single-Thread. 
And if yes, does make it sense to utilize multicore with Bull to run background tasks like massive mongodb-updates (updating my user-profile-avatar would run in req/res loop where as the updates on many many reference documents like in the friendship collection should run in background) which can take minutes or hours, so the users will not even notice when it takes a few minutes or even hours until all users of the network see the new avatar. Or does they mean with blocking code, code which blocks the Event-Loop like cpu-heavy tasks and not I/O operations like database-queries.

I would appreciate every information about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bull is just a library for node.js it doesn't change the fact that node.js runs on a single thread. So you can't expect Bull to solve your single thread problems, however Bull can help you with this.

1. Bull can spawn child processes (sandboxed processes for each job)
2. Yes it makes sense to run heavy tasks in it's own application / process. You can either create a microservice for your task or simply run the background task in a child process spawned by Bull.

I didn't understand the rest of your question (starting with speaking of the massive mongodb queries).

Side note: You usually want to avoid references in MongoDB. MongoDB queries are usually very heavy and/or slow. Instead you want to denormalize data even though this can lead to duplicate stored data.

Comment: Yes, I have a collection User and a collection Friendship. When I want to show friendslist of a User, I query Collection friendship which contain image and name of the friends, so I avoid multiple queries (which would impact performance), I do not save friends in User Collection cause of 16MB limit. When a User updates his profile, all friendship references has to be updated, but since consistency is not important, this is a performance-uncritical operation which can be done in the background. An update will take a while until all friendship lists show the new avatar.

Comment: But what would I do, when a particual User updates his avatar several times in a short time?

Comment: Well your question was about Bull and not about the mongo schema design. An own question for that would be better suited to give a more complete answer for your schema design.